# Android Set textview layout width dynamically

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a listview that consists of two textviews. One for dates, one for names.
Config.xml includes the listview:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/linlay">
</ListView>
```

Row.xml includes the two textviews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <TextView android:id="@+id/left"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/right"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have two more buttons to change the content of the textviews with each other but as the content of the first one (initially) is wider than the second one, i need to set the width of the layout in the code.
Unfortunately there is no txt.setLayoutWidth or similar command, and txt.setWidth() is not working.
I need something like this in this code:

```
 Button sortname = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
  sortname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
  {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        lv1.setAdapter(simpleAdapter2);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,120);
        txt1.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    }
  });
```

This two rows makes the app freeze (stopped unexpectedly):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,120);
    txt1.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
```

Logcat:

```
02-05 22:58:11.040: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.bfarago.nevnap/.MainActivity }
02-05 22:58:11.210: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(415): Shutting down VM
02-05 22:58:11.230: DEBUG/dalvikvm(415): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-05 22:58:11.330: INFO/AndroidRuntime(415): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-05 22:58:12.310: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.bfarago.nevnap/.MainActivity: 1108 ms (total 1108 ms)
02-05 22:58:17.560: DEBUG/dalvikvm(125): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1274 objects / 73520 bytes in 185ms
02-05 22:58:17.660: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(405): Shutting down VM
02-05 22:58:17.660: WARN/dalvikvm(405): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at com.bfarago.nevnap.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:129)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-05 22:58:17.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 22:58:17.680: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.bfarago.nevnap/.MainActivity
02-05 22:58:18.200: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43e9a940 com.bfarago.nevnap/.MainActivity}
02-05 22:58:19.790: INFO/Process(405): Sending signal. PID: 405 SIG: 9
02-05 22:58:19.820: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Process com.bfarago.nevnap (pid 405) has died.
02-05 22:58:19.820: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.bfarago.nevnap/.UpdateService in 5000ms
02-05 22:58:19.820: INFO/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{43fce1d8 com.bfarago.nevnap/com.bfarago.nevnap.MainActivity paused=false}
02-05 22:58:19.920: WARN/InputManagerService(58): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 405 uid 10048
02-05 22:58:24.291: DEBUG/dalvikvm(216): GC_EXPLICIT freed 93 objects / 3736 bytes in 153ms
02-05 22:58:24.901: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.bfarago.nevnap for service com.bfarago.nevnap/.UpdateService: pid=425 uid=10048 gids={1015}
02-05 22:58:28.966: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43e9a940 com.bfarago.nevnap/.MainActivity}
02-05 22:58:29.350: DEBUG/dalvikvm(263): GC_EXPLICIT freed 44 objects / 2032 bytes in 164ms
```

Comment: Where did txt1 come from? Seems it is null.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the method `setLayoutParams` of TextView and pass into it a `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)` where width and height are integers that will specify the width and height. you can keep the height and set the width to whatever you want.

Comment: I modified the row.xml file as you can see. And this code freezes my app, however according to examples i am close.
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,120);
        txt1.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

Comment: Is the app crashing or just freezing? If it's crashing can you provide the logcat output (red text in logcat indicating what made app crash). If it's just freezing I'm not sure what could be wrong...perhaps you need to run the code on the UI thread with the method runOnUI(new Runnable()) of Activity class

Comment: Logcat added. Sorry, it not freezes, it crashes, and when i have those 2 rows.

Comment: Does logcat say anything when it crashes. Usually there will be red text that explains what caused the crash.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you posted the logcat now. You have a NullPointerException in your MainActivity class at line 129. What line of code is that because something in that line is null and hasn't been initialized.