# How to set "width" parameter back to "wrap_content" after set it to a specific value in code?

Tags: android

For example, a TextView, whose original "width" in xml is "wrap_content". Then in java code, I set it to a specific value such as 50px.

Now I want to change it back to "wrap_content", by means of changing the "LayoutParameter", but it didn't work.

So what can I do with it? Thank you!

RESOLVED

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Set textview layout width dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909301/android-set-textview-layout-width-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WRAP_CONTENT` constant defined in `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. Try something like this:

```
TextView tv = // your view here
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = tv.getLayoutParams();
params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I know and I've tried this way. But it didn't work. Seems it won't work AFTER having change width to a specific value.